# rpivotTable select elements drop down menu

Tags: r, shiny, pivot-table, rpivottable

I have created an `rpivotTable` in R and I would like that the different values of the row variable (thousands) to be unselected (or predefine which of them have to be selected) instead of all of them being selected by defect.

Comment: Greeting on SO, please, provide some sample code for reproduction and check [ask] on more useful tips.

Comment: This looks for me as a simple filter task: `new_df <- df[df$Value != 1000, ]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if I've understood the question.

The following code pre-selects elements and variables on the pivottable. Let me know if more details are required.

```
library(rpivotTable)
rpivotTable(
  Titanic,
  rows = "Survived",
  cols = c("Class","Sex"),
  aggregatorName = "Sum as Fraction of Columns",
  inclusions = list( Survived = list("Yes")),
  exclusions= list( Class = list( "Crew")),
  vals = "Freq",
  rendererName = "Table Barchart"
)
```